# Run script to show alert and redirect on IE before error kicks in in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, gatsby

I am running a Gatsby site on Netlify, there is an error / crash specific to IE and I want to show an alert and then redirect to chrome download page if the user is using IE, since I am not supporting IE anyway. I think the crash is caused by a npm package and i dont wanna change to other one because it suit my need.

I put the below script in the Layout component which is run on every page, but the error kicks in and crash the site, the site flash a normal dom before it crash. Am wondering if there are any way to fix it

The script works fine if i change the condition to chrome and run it on chrome to test it

```
//Layout.js


const handleIE = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    let ua = window.navigator.userAgent
    
    if(ua.indexOf('MSIE') > -1) {
      alert('Internet Explorer is not supported. Please use Chrome or Firefox')
      window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/chrome/";
    }
  }
}

<Helmet>
 <script>{handleIE()}</script>
</Helmet>
```

```
// Error log on IE

DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/free.min.css?token=e4232fccfser required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/free-v4-shims.min.css?token=e4232fccfser required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/free-v4-font-face.min.css?token=e4232fccfser required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' File: classic.js, Line: 679, Column: 32
SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' File: classic.js, Line: 679, Column: 32
[object Error]
description "Object doesn't support property or method 'trunc'"
message     "Object doesn't support property or method 'trunc'"
name        "TypeError"
number      -2146827850
stack       "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'trunc'
SCRIPT438:  Object doesn't support property or method 'trunc'
File: framework-7bdbbf12b92c7ff172a2.js, Line: 2, Column: 2442
```

Thank you!!

Comment: is error in IE Crashing the application?

Comment: If the issue is appearing before the script, you must have something offending to IE (which means anything) so, if the application is breaking before the script, you may need to fix it or detect what is it. What's the log prompting?

Comment: @hussain.codes yes, the error cause a crash on IE, i just add a error log in the description

Comment: @FerranBuireu yes, the DOM flash in normal condition before it goes blank, the crash maybe caused by an npm package, i added the error log in the description above just now, it shows Object doest support "trunc"

Comment: If you want to detect if the browser is IE, you need to check `Trident` as well. The code is like this: `function isIE() { return window.navigator.userAgent.match(/(MSIE|Trident)/); }`. Then `if(isIE()) { alert ('IE is not supported') }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IE issue is breaking your application before the script can load. Despite being improbable because you are loading the script in each page that imports the `Layout` component (you may want to use one of the [`gatsby-browser` APIs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/)), your code seems to work.

If you want to be able to bypass this limitation by showing an alert to the IE
user you may need to polyfill the functionality, at least to allow the `trunc` method, which seems to be the offending one.

Said that, this `trunc` method may come from your code (unlikely) or from third-party dependencies. If it's from your code just remove it or find another IE-friendly solution. If it comes from one of the Node modules, you may need to find another solution.

First of all, you need to find which dependency is causing this issue, then, as it is described in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/12399).

Create a `.babelrc` at the root of your Gatsby project:

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "loose": true,
          "modules": "commonjs",
          "useBuiltIns": "entry",
          "targets": { "browsers": [">0.25%", "not dead"] }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "presets": [
    "babel-preset-gatsby",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "debug": true,
        "loose": true,
        "modules": false,
        "useBuiltIns": "entry",
        "targets": { "browsers": [">0.25%", "not dead"] }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ],
    "babel-plugin-macros",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "helpers": true,
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

*Note: you may need to install the required modules.*

Then, you only need to add the polyfill. In your `gatsby-browser.js`:

```
import '@babel/polyfill'

// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export const onClientEntry = () => {
  // Without this function body the import will not be picked up.
 // handleIE()
}
```

Aas I said at the beginning of the post, this `gatsby-browser.js` API (`onClientEntry`) will work for your use case, so you can re-use it. You can load there your script (`handleIE`) to check the user agent. In that way, you will be only loading once per user entry the script, rather X times (one for each page that extends the `Layout` component the user visit)

You may also find useful this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/arnars/2bb1d81fc0955d57fe88a8348695f594) about polyfill IE 10-11 in Gatsby.